# Jquery overriding global value

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am using kendo ui and i dont want duplicate records in my database so what i am doing is using the .Save function of kendo grid to check the record and if exist then return false which is working fine but when i am returning return false then it is still saving the record.

```
function onSave(e) {

         var currentValueForSend = $("[name=RegisterNo]").val();
         alert(currentValueForSend);
         $.ajax(
      {
          url: '/StudentTransaction/CheckRegistrationNumber',
          type: "POST",
          data: { 'RegisterNumber': currentValueForSend },
          success: function (data) {
              alert(data.CurrentRegNo);
              if( data.CurrentRegNo.indexOf('true') >= 0){
                  alert("no duplicate records");
 return false;;
              }

          }
      });

     }
```

i am also defining a global value to override the value but i am not able to override the value

```
function onSave(e) {
     var status;
     var currentValueForSend = $("[name=RegisterNo]").val();
     alert(currentValueForSend);
     $.ajax(
  {
      url: '/StudentTransaction/CheckRegistrationNumber',
      type: "POST",
      data: { 'RegisterNumber': currentValueForSend },
      success: function (data) {
          status = data.CurrentRegNo;

      }
  });

  if (status.indexOf('true') >= 0)) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert("Duplicates not allowed");
      return false;
  }
 }
```

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the async nature of these requests.

The sequence as described in  your code is:

1. make the request
2. check if status is true
3. get the response

You need to use function callbacks to handle this properly. Try something like this:

```
function onSave (e){
  var currentValueForSend = $("[name=RegisterNo]").val();
  alert(currentValueForSend);

  $.ajax({
    url     : '/StudentTransaction/CheckRegistrationNumber',
    type    : "POST",
    data    : { 'RegisterNumber': currentValueForSend },
    success : afterSave
  });
}

function afterSave (data){
  var status = data.CurrentRegNo;
  if (status.indexOf('true') >= 0)) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert("Duplicates not allowed");
      return false;
  }
}
```